# Хлебные крошки (навигационная цепочка) на самописном сайте

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу сделать хлебные крошки посредством php и mysql.
Как пример, есть таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли вытащить название родительской таблицы по внешнему ключу? Или в запросах нужно обязательно название всех таблиц писать? Может быть есть иной способ?

Интересует способ создания крошек именно из БД.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Несовсем понятно что вы хотите, рекурсивный запрос?

Comment: Думаю, что да. Просто я не совсем понимаю механизм образования крошек из БД.

Comment: Не нужно делать этого на стороне БД, делайте это на стороне PHP с помощью рекурсивной функции, и не снизу вверх как вы хотели а с верху вниз до каждой веточки дерева

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/p_QNumx-eIjnvA если я вас верно понял, вы хотите подобное меню таскать из БД? с неограниченым уровнем вложености?

Comment: Да, хотел именно так. И, если делать это на php, то как мне взаимодействовать с БД? Если я правильно понял, то из БД берется и URL и название страниц.

Comment: На стороне php стройте дерево, ненужно напрягать ради этого базу данных.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, где тогда хранить те же URL с названиями страниц?

Comment: Например в БД, всё зависит от вашей структуры сайта, у меня все обращения к сайту идут через один файл, в бд хранится `ID,Name,Parrent, sort_order, Files` ..  где ID - текстовое поле(аля ссылка), Name - имя выводимое на экран, Parrent - ID родителя, sort_order - порядок вывода в пределах родителя, Files - файлы для подключения...
т.е. все обращения идут через `Index.php?page=ID`

Comment: Не совсем понятна фраза "есть таблицЫ". Я вижу тут только одну таблицу и в ней несколько записей. Если вы хотите с этим серьезно работать, то рекомендую обновить MySQL до 8 версии или использовать другую СУБД (PostgeSQL, oracle, ms sql, SQLite), они все поддерживают рекурсивные запросы, которые позволят получить готовое дерево прямо из БД (см. recusive CTE)